is there a way to capture window minimize event in tcl/tk?
I am trying to capture window minimize event in tcl/tk. is there a way to capture window minimize event in tcl/tk?
Also Configure event is not raised If i click on taskbar icon to minimize/restore the window.
Following is the example code. Click on taskbar button to minimize and restore. Configure/Map/Unmap events are not fired at all.
proc confEvent {} {
    puts [wm state .t]
}

proc mapEvent {} {
    puts Map
}

proc unmapEvent {} {
    puts Unmap
}

wm withdraw .
toplevel .t -width 400 -height 400
bind .t <Configure> {confEvent}
bind .t <Map> {mapEvent}
bind .t <Unmap> {unmapEvent}


The answer to your other question has demonstrated on binding <Unmap> event. So I wonder what your issue is.

problem is that   isn't fired when clicked on taskbar button.

It is better to provide a [mre].

If you use wish to execute the script, then puts will not work in Windows. Use tclsh instead, but you need to add package require Tk at the beginning of the script.

@acw1668, i am running it on CentOS 7.

Your code works fine on my Debian 12.7.

For me it worked on windows. and didn't work on CentOS 7, Rocky Linux (Wayland and X11 both) and WSL.

Very weird that <Unmap> isn't being delivered on X11.

@acw1668 i tried it on debian also. it isn't working correctly on debian also. just like centos7 and rocky linux  event is fired only on startup. subsequent minimize, restore action doesn't raise / event.

It works for me, see here.

@acw1668 which window manager do you use on Debian? is it GNOME classic or is it Xfce4?

I am using LXQt .

@acw1668,  behavior is dependent on desktop environment. it works on kde, xfce4 and lxqt. but it doesn't work in gnome.

In that case, the problem is that Gnome simply isn't sending the event, in violation of the ICCM. Not much we can do about that; it's the kind of bug they close without even considering fixing...
